# Python - Numeric Literal expressions

Tags: python, syntax-error, numeric, literals

Can somebody help me understand why Python does the following?

```
>>> 1,024
SyntaxError: invalid token

>>> 1,024.46
(1, 24.46)
```

The 1st numeric literal 1,024 returns a SyntaxError as commas are never used in numeric literals in Python.

However, the 2nd numeric literal returns the number 1,024.46 as two different numbers, even though it is one number and it does not throw an Error.

I am trying to understand what Python perceives the 2nd number to be and how is it different from the 1st one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python considers two comma-separated values like that to be a tuple (hence the parentheses). The reason the first one is a syntax error and the second isn't is that for a float, starting with a 0 is permitted, while for an integer it isn't. So `(1, 024)` is a syntax error, `(1, 024.46)` isn't, because `024` is not a valid integer but `024.46` is a valid float.